# How to make public link and private endpoint link of a azure redis service work simultaneously

Tags: azure, redis, azure-storage, azure-private-link

How to make public link and private endpoint link of an azure Redis service work simultaneously.

Can we keep both functionalities work simultaneously like outside users using the original public IP link and internal users using a private endpoint link to connect to an Azure Redis instance or azure storage account?
I have this kind of scenario

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to enforce somehow the DNS resolution happening within your internal network so that any internal calls fetches the record created in the `Private DNS Zone` alongside the `Private Endpoint`.

Within your Virtual Network, you can for example [change the DNS servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances). Be careful, it might have severe impacts, as you might also need to re-specify how to reach other resources within Azure (since **Azure DNS *168.63.129.16*** is gone at that point). Be also aware about the [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances#specify-dns-servers) if you have several DNS servers at different levels.